# I had a tax return completed in Australia and New Zealand and have been taxed in both. How does this work?

Tags: income-tax, australia, foreign-income, moving, new-zealand

I moved of to Australia part way through the tax year and then returned to New Zealand and worked.

When I filed my tax return, it was automatically complete in New Zealand due to the IR3 file, but a tax return in Australia was done.

My New Zealand one was completed beforehand with my Australia one to follow. My Australia one states that I owe an amount of tax due to not being a tax resident for tax purposes, and I incurred interest. My NZ tax was based off my whole income earned, including international. But that came back saying I owed tax as well.

Can someone explain how this may have occured, or how I can possibly resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Most states have anti-double-taxation treaties. But exact procedure may be a complicated matter. I think you should get a tax attorney involved.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, each country taxes by his own rules. That means that worst case, you *do* owe taxes in all countries you worked or lived in.

However, most countries have made contracts (treaties) to avoid double taxation. Typically, in the tax declaration for the second country, you enter the amount of taxes already paid in the first country, and the tax gets then lowered to the higher of the two.